# Why are branded coffee stores in India as expensive as those in western countries?

Tags: macroeconomics, price

When I say branded ones, I am thinking of things like Tim Hortons, Starbucks, and also Indian local brands like Cafe Coffee day, Third wave coffee and so on.

One would assume, that since India is a "third world country", that the price of everything would drop hard, but if you really see it, you would find the price are same or more than those in many  western countries:

I found this nice graph:
[image]

The domestic brands are slightly cheaper and may go drop till around 3$ but still, it is very high compared to rest of the things.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the date of the data on the map.  With all prices quoted in dollars, exchange rates would be one factor.  The Turkish lira, for example, has depreciated from about 8 to 29 to the US dollar over the last 3 years.